# await AsyncStorage return a promise instead value

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I have an async function that calls AsyncStorage.getItem but always returns a promise.

I tried to use .then clause but the result is similar

I tried to use AsyncStorage.getItem out of the function but I get the error "await is a reserved word"

```
getDataStorage = async () => {
    console.log("getDataStorage");
    var data = '';
    try {
      data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('dataStorage');
      console.log("getting data " + data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("----" + error.message);
    }
  };

componentDidMount(){
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    var data = this.getDataStorage();
    console.log(data);
}
```

The result is first displays the promise then prints the value that I get with getItem().

I want to get the value, I suppose with await the function waits for the result of getItem, is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, await functions wait for the result. But, in your case its only waiting till returning promise, so you have to change your code as:

```
    componentDidMount = async () => {
            console.log("componentDidMount");
            data = await this.getDataStorage();
            console.log(data);
        }
```